# Transmission-cli is leaving .part files

Tags: command-line, bittorrent, transmission

I recently developed a PHP script to automatically download torrents with `transmission-cli`. I did consider using `deluge-console` but that did not support download locations (`-w`), the problem is:

Whenever I download a torrent, multiple `.part` files get saved instead of normal files, for example, if a torrent file contains `a.txt b.ini c.bin` files, the client downloads `a.txt b.ini.part c.bin.part`, and it seems like the download does not finish. If someone has any answers or any alternatives to `transmission-cli`, it would help A LOT.

You can see a picture of the problem here:
[image]

Comment: Silly question, but are you certain that those Shin Megami Tensei OST files have finished downloading? Are there a sufficient number of seeds to allow the completion of those files? Based solely on the information provided, this does not seem to be a problem beyond “slower than desired Torrent completion times” 

Comment: @matigo i actually think so, that's if the cli command stays open until the download finishes: the client I've made automatically deletes source files after the command exits (i did this for zip files and used it with torrents too). Is there any way to check what's the status from another shell instance? Cause, the .torrent file got deleted so i think the download ended

Comment: The `*.part` files are portions of the download that get downloaded as bandwidth permits. When all the `.part` files are downloaded,  `transmission` knits them together to produce the downloaded file, and deletes the `.part` files. The existence of `.part` files implies the downloads are incomplete, or that `transmission` has died early.

Comment: @waltinator to download the files I'm trying to execute the command in the background by using `( transmission-cli ./dir/file.torrent -w ./dir/ ;rm -f ./dir/ ) > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`. This basically executes the transmission command, awaits it to exit and then executes the rm command to delete the .torrent file, everything in the background so I don't slow down php execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating the .config/transmission subdirectories inside of /var/www/ which is www-data's home directory.